# OpenCV with Python - reading images in a loop

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I'm using OpenCV's `imread` function to read my images into Python, for further processing as a NumPy array later in the pipeline. I know that OpenCV uses BGR instead of RGB, and have accounted for it, where required. But one thing that stumps me is why I get these differing outputs for the following scenarios?

Reading an image directly into a single works fine. The plotted image (using `matplotlib.pyplot`) reproduces my .tiff/.png input correctly.

```
img_train = cv2.imread('image.png')
plt.imshow(img_train)
plt.show()
```

[image]

When I use `cv2.imread` in a loop (for reading from a directory of such images - which is my ultimate goal here), I create an array as follows:

```
files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
img_train = np.empty([len(files), height, width, channel])
for n in range(0, len(files)):
    img_train[n] = cv2.imread(join(mypath, files[n]))
plt.imshow(img_train[n])
plt.show()
```

[image]

When I try to cross check and plot the image obtained thus, I get a very different output. Why so? How do I rectify this so that it looks more like my input, like in the first case? Am I reading the arrays correctly in the second case, or is it flawed?

Otherwise, is it something that stems from Matplotlib's plotting function? I do not know how to cross check for this case, though.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Does img_train.shape in the first case and img_train[0].shape in the second case give you the same tuples?

Comment: @DrK yep, they did. I posted here too soon, I suppose. Found the answer. Updated below. Although, I'm not sure I understand why the dtype (as specified in my answer) affects it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely trivial solution.
`np.empty` creates an array of dtype float by default.
Changing this to uint8 as in the first case with OpenCV alone worked fine.